# How to make a private field available in Groovy script by an annotation

Tags: java, groovy, annotations

For instance I have a class:

```
public class Model1 {
  @Bind private int val;
}
```

and I have an annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface Bind {


}
```

I would like to pass an object of `Model1` class to the Groovy script but I will not have the `val` available in that script. Can I make it avaiable by `@Bind` annotation?

Comment: I assume `Model1` is a Java class?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have accessors for your private field, the only way to achieve what you want is to use reflection.

First, get all fields of your model, :

```
Model1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()
```

It will return list of declared fields.
Then, iterate over list and check if field is annotated with Bind:

```
field.getDeclaredAnnotation(Bind.class)
```

this method will return null if field is not annotated with 'Bind' annotation.

And finally, make private field accessible:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Now do watever you need with field

Comment: But then even if you pass object of `Model1`class you can't access its' fields in the Groovy script.